# Jquery Ajax dynamic forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamically generated form and I want to submit to a PHP file using `$.ajax`. How do I do that and what I can I assign on the `data` property?

Comment: Reading is believing [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use **AJAX**..

```
function ajaxfunc()
{
           var datafield = $('#frm').serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "query_page.php",
            data:   datafield,
            success: function(html){
            // data you want to return on.
            }
        });

}
```

i think this makes you happy and satisfied.

Comment: Also `type: 'POST'`, if this is OP's chosen method.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy : yes,we can use POST also..Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.